# How can I debug my kotlin koan?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm fiddling around a bit while working through the [Kotlin Koans in IDEA](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/edu-tools-learner.html) and I'd like to debug my code.

How do I run my koan task under the debugger?

Failing that, where do I at least see the output of a `println` in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Kotlin project and put your code inside it and then debug it like a Java project.

You can set breakpoints, see the output, step in, step over, etc.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, but it feels like a last resort. Creating a new project takes you totally outside the flow of the exercises. And the test harness that actually provides the data and invokes your code is usually invisible to the student, so you'd have to peek under the hood to find that file or re-create it ...